# Get Previous and Next Days

Tags: javascript

I am pulling varchar dates from a db table, and trying use them to get the date of both the previous day and next day. In the example below, I would have grabbed 2020-03-26 from my table. I am trying to figure out how to get both 2020-03-25 and 2020-03-27 saved as variables that I can then use. I have figured out that in order to get the date the exact format that I want I have to use the toISOString and slice off the first 10 characters, but I am unsure how to get the previous and next days, especially if a month crossover had occurred.

```
var tableDate = new Date('2020-03-26')
tableDate = tableDate.toISOString().slice(0,10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```js
let tableDate = new Date('2020-03-26');

// function to increment
function incrementDate(date, days) {
  let result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  return result;
}

// funtion to decrement
function decrementDate(date, days) {
  let result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() - days);
  return result;
}

console.log(incrementDate(tableDate, 1).toISOString().split('T')[0]);
console.log(decrementDate(tableDate, 1).toISOString().split('T')[0]);
```

Comment: Why the - 2 and not - 1 though?

Comment: because when we use first `tableDate` then it updated the value to `tableDate` value, here -1 will also work if you keep `2020-03-26` this date into another variable and use that variable in `decreased_one_date`

Comment: Ahhh okay I got it now. Thank you!

Comment: I also updated the answer using functions

Answer (score 0):

The decidedly easiest way is using [dayjs](https://day.js.org/).

With it set up you'd use it something like,

```js
const tableDate = new Date('2020-03-26')
const dayBefore = dayjs(tableDate).subtract(1, 'day')
const dayAfter = dayjs(tableDate).add(1, 'day')
```

You can then apply `.toISOString()`, or you can simply use `.format()` to get the exact output you'd prefer from the outset.